# Applying for wife's UK visitor visa after the trip is postponed

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

I was granted UK standard visitor visa to travel in January 2022 to visit my son valid from February-August. However, due to my younger daughter who is in school in India got sick in February and I had to postpone my trip to the UK.

Now since my daughter is well and will be enjoying her summer vacation at my parent's house, I'm planning to take my wife along with me to the UK.

Can I apply for my wife's visa now? Because there is a question on the application: *"Will you be traveling with your spouse?"* Do I have to explain the reason for me postponing my trip on her visa application?

Comment: What kind of travel history do you and your wife have? If this was a first-time visa it *might* be more likely that applying for a visa for your wife to accompany you could jeopardise your existing visa. But really, no-one can predict the outcome.

Answer (score 3):

If you got your visa based on the fact that your wife was staying home and one of your ties to your home country was your wife, you may find that applying for a visa for her can cost you your visa.
You will have to mention your visa when you apply for her, explaining the difference in circumstances and why you now apply for the two of you rather than just one.

It can be better not to apply if it is essential for you to travel and your other ties to your home country are weak.
On the other hand, if your visa is secure it will be better to travel together, and if she can get a visa without you risking yours it will be no problem. (Sorry, I do not have enough experience to make a prediction here.)

The reason you postponed your trip is in itself not that important, but the fact that you were going to travel alone but now with your spouse is important.